# Unable to send messages from iPod to users with non-Apple devices

Tags: ios, messages

I have an iPod touch 5, and it won't let me send messages to non-Apple users. I've tried to find help in a lot of websites, but my iPod is still not letting me text non-Apple users.

Answer (score 7):

The iPod can only send iMessages, not SMS. iMessage is a service from Apple that only work on Apple devices. It is possible to send regular SMS from an iPod if you have an iPhone on the same Apple-ID and on the same Wi-Fi network. If you do not have an iPhone all messages is sent from your e-mail address not a phone number.

Answer (score 3):

In order to be able to send a traditional text message, you need access to a mobile phone network (and a way of "paying" for the message-usually part of your PAYG sim contract etc). An iPad or iPod touch can send iMessages but will not be able to send a text unless it is linked to an iPhone with a valid mobile sim.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answers are basically correct, you can use a third party app. 
Try Google Hangouts/Google Voice (your Google Voice phone Number is associated with your hangouts identity) or Pinger, as well as others (search the App Store for "SMS" or "texting app").

These apps will assign a phone number so that you can send and receive SMS messages.

Comment: @moshe thanks for the edit, but your info was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, Yes you can send normal Text messages on your ipod touch. There is something called google voice, all you need is a google account.

1. Go to [google voice](https://voice.google.com).
2. Set up your new free phone number.
3. Download the google voice app on your ipod touch.
   You are now ready to go you can make phone calls and send text messages on your ipod touch with the google voice app.